# How to turn inputted words into a list of URLs in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, url

I am a newbie. I am trying to generate a list of links from words inputted in Python. But it always produces only the last link although I input more than one.

I have tried to look for the answers but just cannot seem to find the right one. Maybe I am still too inexperienced to understand and apply them to my case. Anyway, how can I fix this?

My code:

```
search = input()

Split = search.split(' ')
print(Split)

for word in Split:  
    URL = 'https://samplenotspamdotcom/'+word
    print(URL)

URL_List = URL.split(' ')  
print(URL_List)
```

My output:

```
['https://samplenotspamdotcom/not']
```

Expected output:

```
['https://samplenotspamdotcom/why', 'https://samplenotspamdotcom/not']
```

Comment: At some point in your code you need to create a new list, and then append some items to it. See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for commenting. I see. I still don't really understand even after reading the documentation. However, I think it's still a good opprotunity to learn. I just have to try it until make it. So, creating a new list and appending it it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to achieve that first option is to concatenate links with a space in between each link and then split them on space or create a blank list and in loop add them to the list.

Option 1:

```
URL = ''
for word in Split:  
    URL += 'https://samplenotspamdotcom/'+word+' '
    print(URL)
URL.strip() #to remove any extra space on the end
URL_List = URL.split(' ')  
print(URL_List)
```

Option2

```
URLS = []
for word in Split:  
    URLS.append('https://samplenotspamdotcom/'+word)
print(URLS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works and helps me learn new things. Although the option one needs some fixing since it adds extra  `''` at the end, it still works regardless. Unfortunatey, I cannot give you an upvote yet, so sorry about that. I will give you one when I can.